# Push array inside array element in mongoose & node.js

Tags: arrays, mongoose

Can I push array element inside an Array element using Push ?

```
newPatient.EmergencyContacts.push({
    emerContact_Name: String,
    emerContact_Relation: String,
    emerContact_Addresses.push({
        emerContact_AddressType: String,
        emerContact_AddressLine1: String,
        emerContact_AddressLine2: String,
        emerContact_City: String,
        emerContact_Town: String,
        emerContact_Village: String,
        emerContact_PolicStation: String,
        emerContact_District: String,
        emerContact_State: String,
        emerContact_PinCode: Number
    }),
    emerContact_ContactInfo.push({
        Phone: String,
        Email: String
    })
});
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't have keys for the values `emerContact_Addresses.push()` and `emerContact_ContactInfo.push()`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ...  What are the keys I need to provide ?

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html     I am using the push as shown in this documentation . But this does not tell how to do when array is nested inside array element